# Asus laptop draws power from socket only when power-off/sleeping/hibernated

Tags: power-supply, asus-laptop

I have three year old Asus laptop running Windows 11. A month or so ago, it occasionally started failing to draw power from the socket when the laptop is in use. The battery was completely worn out so I took it out and started working without a battery.

Now it began to shut down abruptly even when connected to power supply. I then got a new (non-OEM) battery installed. The power drawing problem did not go away though I had much longer battery life.

I was forced to work on battery and when it is nearly drained, I had to put the laptop to sleep and toggle the power switch. Then it charges the battery. After an hour, when I turn it on, the battery is nearly charged but now it again shows as unplugged and only runs on battery.

Then I took it to a service center who reasoned that it might be related to heat sensors switching off power intake. They performed a general cleaning (remove microfibers and clean some boards with isopropyl). That seemed to resolve the issue completely for a few days. Then it started happening again.

Is this likely to be a faulty adapter (3-year old) or some internal issue with the laptop or something else?

p.s. I work in a place with some voltage fluctuation.

Comment: How is an old Asus laptop running Windows 11? Did the service center test the power supply?

Comment: Are you able to test a different cable/charger? Sometimes the brick can overheat or go bad. The laptop itself should not stop charging due to heat

Comment: In addition to the above, the additional drain could have damaged the charging circuit. You need to get it serviced.

Comment: @harrymc It came preinstalled with Win10 and then auto-updated to 11 over the air. The service center did not test the power supply.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thanks. Yes that's what I'll try next.

Comment: @John Thanks. You mean the PMIC?